# How to install MySQLi on a cPanel-managed server?

Tags: php, mysqli, cpanel

I have an existing web application that was written over the past few years. I chose mysqli as the method for accessing a MySQL database. That works fine. My problem is that I'm deploying to a 3rd party web host server - WHM/cPanel - and I cannot find a way to get mysqli installed on this server. I've tried too many things to list here - including everything I could find on this site. 
This server uses yum. It has PHP5.4 - MySQL 5.5 When I run phpinfo on it there is a MySQL section but no MySQLi section. My code crashes with "class mysqli not found" error. 
The documentation on PHP.net states that mysqli was included in the standard distribution starting with PHP 5.0. I know for a fact that is no longer true - the last 3 machines i've built with Ubuntu did not have mysqli on them I had to find/install it using apt-get install php5-mysqlnd I cannot find a package for mysqli on this server. 
Rewriting all my SQL to use the native driver will not be a simple task. i'd prefer to avoid that. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the last few ubuntus have used mariadb instead, not mysql.

Comment: You don't have to rewrite anything or lose your calm, what you need to do is [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php) and recompile your PHP with `--with-mysqli` option. It's actually simpler to do that than to install from a package to be honest. I don't know why your package installation fails, I'm pretty sure you missed something somewhere, but don't panic, configure stuff on your own, hit that `make` command and relax.

Comment: the package installation does not fail - I do not know what package to install

Answer (score 3):

The answer to my own question: WHM --> Software --> EasyApache

My current configuration was shown at the top and was selected (radio button). I edited that and selected Exhaustive List of Options. I was able to select several items including mysqli, mbstring, json, mcrypt, XML, date, openssl, sockets, soap, xmlwriter ... hard to believe so many of those were missing many were my next problem I just had not yet discovered.

EasyApache recompiled apache/php for me and restarted apache automagically. MySQLi was now included along with the other elements I selected.

To further configure PHP - I had to use phpinfo to find the php.ini file it is loading and edit that as root (sudo). There is a facility located in

WHM --> Service Configuration --> PHP Configuration Editor

that can be used instead but it is unlikely all options will be available using this page. Also: see note below: I had to manually edit php.ini to configure the new stuff.

I'd like to also point out that there are additional sections that should have been added to the php.ini file but were not. There should be a section to configure mysqli (separate from mysql [native driver]), mbstring, soap etc. These are not present in the php.ini file on my server after running EasyApache to update PHP. I had to edit the php.ini file and add the sections for them and restart apache. Just FYI

Answer (score 0):

You are using cPanel control panel on your server so you need to enable this mysqli on your server through WHM >> Software >> EasyApache (Apache Update)

OR you can do it same through command line using following command.

```
/scripts/easyapache
```

Comment: I do not see the connection. I navigated to the EasyApache web page and it gives me a choice between Apache 2.2 / PHP 5.4 / MPM PreFork or Apache 2.4 / PHP 5.4 / MPM PreFork - How does installing Apache 2.4 instead of Apache 2.2 change anything? The only thing I can do on this page is select one option (radio button) and click build - it then recompiles apache and php with the same thing I have now. I assume that if this were not a 3rd party hosting site I would be able to use this facility to somehow configure PHP? Given that this facility appears to be  useless are there any other choices?

Comment: I found it. I do have the ability to customize this and have found the ability to select MySQLi  I was pointed to this facility before now but it seemed like all I could do is chose between a list of pre-assembled configurations none of which met my requirements. I finally figured out to click the little wheel image and get a menu system of pages that allows me to customize every element of the apache / PHP software. I need to study these options i'm not familiar with all of these. But this is definitely the right place. I'll probably have questions about some of these but for now thank you.