# After upgrade to PHP 7.0, my website does not start up

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cpanel

I was using `PHP 4.0` and recently upgraded to `PHP 7.0` with cPanel. But now my website is down, it shows the following error: `Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.`

Does this mean that I will have to completely reinstall & reconfigure all websites, or is there an easy solution within cPanel?

-- snip --

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead. Since you're using Wordpress, try upgrading your Wordpress installation or switch your config to use PDO or Mysqli

Comment: please write down the code to see what is the problem with buhehe.de

Comment: What must i find in wp-config?

Comment: What code do u mean? I use wordpress. Which code should i provide?

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php7 Installation of wordpress on nginx throwing PHP installation missing MySQL extension which is required by WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200180/php7-installation-of-wordpress-on-nginx-throwing-php-installation-missing-mysql)

Comment: WordPress 4.9.2

Comment: But how can i do it in cpanel?

sudo apt-get install php-mysqlnd php-mysqli
sudo /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm restart

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662519/how-to-install-mysqli-on-a-cpanel-managed-server

Comment: Alternatively switch to PHP 5.6 - and start preparing for PHP 7.1; both 5.6 and 7.0 leave support completely in December but you should have fewer compatibility issues with 5.6, buying you the time to migrate.

Comment: @NikaKhachidze before doing anything else. I would recommend changing ALL your passwords. They have just been leaked to the world.

Answer (score 3):

PHP 4? Wow :-P

All the `mysql_whatever()` commands have been deprecated a while back , and completely removed in v7 (see http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php).

You should now update your code to use the `PDO` API.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

See this guide for steps involved.

https://www.sitepoint.com/migrate-from-the-mysql-extension-to-pdo/

You may have other things needing fixed too. Always check the changelogs, and look at these migration guides, which lists everything you need to know about the upgrade.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

Your wordpress should be able to update itself by clicking something in the admin section. I can't remember specifically, but here's a link that can help. You just need to worry about the code you wrote yourself.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress

Comment: Don't forget the fact that he is using Wordpress, this means that he will not be doing any scripting himself. Better to link an upgrade/migration manual for WordPress

Comment: wordpress is able to update itself, he only needs to worry about the code he and his team wroite

Comment: Yes but this error indicates he is using an old version of WordPress on PHP 7.0

Comment: This is why self-hosting WordPress is almost always a terrible idea. Unless you're prepared to patch WordPress, PHP, and the server itself on a regular and *emergency basis* you're going to get into trouble. There's many high-quality WordPress providers out there at various price-points. Most will keep your installation and back-end patched and secure as part of that package.

Comment: I like *using* wordpress, but as a developer I have to say the code looks like it was written in 2003, and unfortunately this encourages devs to code in a similarly atrocious manner. It doesn't surprise me at all when they run into trouble.